# Adding api to an existing rails project with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need to add some api for moobile to my existing project in rails. I am using devise gem for authentication. The first api needed are user registration, login, profile update , some posting feature etc.I am following https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth this to create api, but it creates user.rb and migration as well as a duplicate routes. Am I doing something wrong. Please help me to solve the issue . Thanks in advance

Comment: No, you don't need to create model and migrations again. You can use existing model for your api

Comment: I am a newbee so can you please explain in detail or give any useful links that I can refer to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added devise token authentication for api. Also created a seperate application controller for api's. All the api controller extends this application controller. The api routes starts with /api/

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says:

> A model will be created in the app/models directory. If the model already exists, a concern will be included at the top of the file.

And

> A migration file will be created in the db/migrate directory. Inspect the migrations file, add additional columns if necessary, and then run the migration:

So

> Can I use this gem alongside standard Devise?
>   Yes! But you will need to enable the support of separate routes for standard Devise.

https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#can-i-use-this-gem-alongside-standard-devise

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I wouldn't use `Devise` for your `authentication` but would create a custom one next to `Devise` just for your `API`. Devise can become a bit buggy later on in the process when using it for `API-authentication`. Then for your `authorization` you could use `Pundit`. You might want to use `Regulator` next to it for `controller namespaced authorization polices`(it's not under development anymore, but it does the job).

There's a nice tutorial about this process:
[API Tutorial](https://labs.kollegorna.se/blog/2015/04/build-an-api-now/)

Here you can find `Pundit`:
[Pundit Gem](https://github.com/elabs/pundit)

And here's the `Regulator gem`:
[Regulator Gem](https://github.com/coryodaniel/regulator)